# Get shared viewmodel with constructor arguments between Activity and Fragment using Koin

Tags: android, android-viewmodel, koin

I am using koin dependency injection. My Activity is in Java and Fragment is in Kotlin. The Viewmodel has constructor arguments.

Currently I am trying this in Activity

```
MyViewmodel viewmodel = get(MyViewmodel.class, null, () -> parametersOf(this));
```

And in Fragment

```
private val viewModel: MyViewmodel by sharedViewModel()
```

I am getting different instances. How to share a single instance here?

Comment: did you find a solution to this?

Comment: Instead of "by sharedViewmodel" use "by activityViewModels"

Comment: Instead of getting viewmodel instance in Java activty, write an extension function to get viewmodel instance in kotlin, this function can directly be imported in Java class.                                                                                            
 fun LifecycleOwner.getMyViewModel(): MyViewModel {
    // Move this to MainActivity file after it get converted to Kotlin
    val viewModel: MyViewModel by viewModel()
    return viewModel
}

Answer (score 0):

I think you should check your initialization.
See [sample](https://insert-koin.io/docs/reference/koin-android/viewmodel). Your question doesn't have enough information for a full answer.